# How can I decrypt the Triplestore files of an RDF4J database?

Tags: triplestore, rdf4j

I am currently trying to read the files of an RDF4J triplestore from the universAAL platform and put them into an InfluxDB to merge the data from different smart living systems.
However, I have noticed that the individual index files of the Native repository are encrypted/unreadable (See image below).
Is there any experience from the community on how to get human readable content out of the RDF4J files (namespace, triples.prop, triples-cosp, triples-posc, triples-spoc, values.hash, values.dat, values.id) and merge them into another database?
The documentation of RDF4J did not help me here, so I could not create a decent export.

[Encrypted File from Triplestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaky4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are not encrypted, they're simply a binary format, optimized for efficient storage and retrieval, used by RDF4J's [Native Store](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/repository/#native-rdf-repository) database implementation. They're not meant for direct manipulation.

The easiest way to convert them to readable RDF is to spin up a Native Store on top of them and then use the RDF4J API to query/export its data. Assuming you have a complete set of data files it should be  as simple as something like this:

```java
Repository rep = new SailRepository(new NativeStore(new File("/path/to/datafiles/");

try(RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection()) {
    conn.export(Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, System.out));
}
finally {
    rep.shutDown();
}
```

Obviously, replace `System.out` with a `FileOutputstream` if you want to write the data to file rather than the console. And change `RDFFormat.TURTLE` to something else if you want a different syntax format.

Comment: Worked as expected. Many Thanks! :)